# ¿Cómo crear un select dinámico con jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

Estoy tratando de que el segundo `select` sea dinámico dependiendo del valor del primer `select` y mi código es el siguiente:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let contenido1 = ['Frutas', 'Verduras', 'Hortalizas']
  let contenido2 = ['Mesa', 'Cocina', 'Refrigerador']

  $("#select_principal").on("change", function() {
    let select_principal = $(this).val()

    if (select_principal === "Primer Select") {
      for (let i = 0; i < contenido1.length; i++) {
        $('#select_dinamico').append('<option>' + contenido1[i] + '</option>');
      }
    }

    if (select_principal === "Segundo Select") {
      for (let i = 0; i < contenido2.length; i++) {
        $('#select_dinamico').append('<option>' + contenido2[i] + '</option>');
      }
    }

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <select name="" id="select_principal">
    <option value="Primer Select">Primer Select</option>
    <option value="Segundo Select">Segundo Select</option>
    <option value="tercer Select">tercer Select</option>
  </select>

  <select name="" id="select_dinamico">

  </select>
</div>
```

También que cuando seleccione la segunda opción del primer `select` se muestre el `select` dinámico que corresponde y así sucesivamente.

Comment: Y el problema cual sería??

Comment: ah, el problema es que cuando selecciono la segunda opción del primer select se mezclan o juntan los valores en el select dinámico

Comment: Porque no borraste lo anterior antes del for pones  $('#select_dinamico').empty(); o algo asi

Comment: si no quieres lo anterior no uses el  .append ..... usa .html, asi le estas añadiendo elementos a lo que ya tenias

Comment: lo que tiene .html solo te retorna el último elemnto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vas por buen camino.

Hice algunas modificaciones y comenté las líneas de código modificadas.

La idea es dejar el `HTML` del `select_dinamico` vacío en cada cambio del `select_pricipal`. Luego, declarar una variable vacía para contener los `option` en cada iteración del ciclo. Posteriormente se agregan los `option` a la variable y finalmente se asignan al `select_dinamico` las opciones que correspondan según el `select_principal` seleccionado.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let contenido1 = ['Frutas', 'Verduras', 'Hortalizas'];
  let contenido2 = ['Mesa', 'Cocina', 'Refrigerador'];

  $("#select_principal").on("change", function() {
    //Eliminar el html del select_dinamico
    $('#select_dinamico').html('');
    //Declarar la variable opciones que almacenará los option
    let opciones = '';
    
    let select_principal = $(this).val();

    if (select_principal === "Primer Select") {
      for (let i = 0; i < contenido1.length; i++) {
        //Agregar los option en cada iteración
        opciones += '<option>' + contenido1[i] + '</option>';
      }
    } else if (select_principal === "Segundo Select") {
      for (let i = 0; i < contenido2.length; i++) {
        //Agregar los option en cada iteración
        opciones += '<option>' + contenido2[i] + '</option>';
      }
    }
    //Asignar los option correspondientes
    $('#select_dinamico').html(opciones);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <select name="" id="select_principal">
    <!-- se declara el primer option vacío y con el atributo hidden para que se oculte al hacer el primer cambio -->
    <option value="" hidden>Seleccione</option>
    <option value="Primer Select">Primer Select</option>
    <option value="Segundo Select">Segundo Select</option>
    <option value="tercer Select">tercer Select</option>
  </select>

  <select name="" id="select_dinamico">

  </select>
</div>
```